# Prove there is only one solution and find only solution of $1 + \sqrt 2 x +\sin x - \cos x = 0 $

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Show that the equation:

$$1 + \sqrt 2 x +\sin x - \cos x = 0 $$

has one and only one solution. Can you identify the solution?

I am not sure the best way to approach this question. I know that there is only one solution then it only cuts the x-axis at one point. I know that $x=0$ is a solution, but do not know how to prove it is the only solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about $x=0$?

Comment: No actually I hadn't, but that does work as a solution. Still not sure how to prove it is the only solution though.

Comment: Do you have calculus tools? The derivative on the left hand side only has one zero in $[0,2\pi]$, which is meaningful for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\sin(x)-\cos(x)=\sqrt2\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)
$$
reduces this to showing that $x+\sin(x)$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Not familiar with that identity! How's it derived?

Comment: Use the formula for the sine of a difference, and the fact that $\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: You mean sin(α – β) = sin(α) cos(β) – cos(α) sin(β) for  α,β $\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: that would be the one.

Comment: I need to review my trigonometry and basic Euclidean geometry,seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $1+x\sqrt{2} +\sin x-\cos x=0$

can be seen as the intersection of two curves

$y=1+x\sqrt{2} $ and $y=\cos x - \sin x$

and from the graphic representation it follows that $x=0$ is the one and only solution

Hope it helps

$$...$$

[image]